# I want just the insert query for a temp table

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I am using C#.Net and Sql Server ( Windows Application ). I had created a temporary table.  When a button is clicked, temporary table (`#tmp_emp_details`) is created. 
 I am having another button called "insert Values" and also 5 textboxes. The values that are entered in the textbox are used and whenever `com.ExecuteNonQuery();` line comes, it throws an error message `Invalid object name '#tbl_emp_answer'.`. Below is the set of code.. Please give me a solution.

Code for insert (in insert value button):

```
private void btninsertvalues_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
        {
            username = txtusername.Text;
            examloginid = txtexamloginid.Text;
            question = txtquestion.Text;
            answer = txtanswer.Text;
            useranswer = txtanswer.Text;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=tempdb;Integrated Security=True;");
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("Insert into #tbl_emp_answer values('"+username+"','"+examloginid+"','"+question+"','"+answer+"','"+useranswer+"')", con);
            con.Open();
            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You said you created the temporary table `#tmp_emp_details` but are trying to insert into a table of a different name, `#tbl_emp_answer`.

- Have you created the table `#tbl_emp_answer`?
- Should you be inserting into **`#tmp_emp_details`** instead?